# React Styled Components Extend

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

i'm trying to re-use and extend a `styled-component` with no luck. I suspect i haven't quite grasped how to properly use `styled-components`

I have a component that renders a chevron icon, based on what `icon` prop is passed to it. What i want to be able to do is export this component, then import it and extend its styles. ie - in this example remove its padding in `Header.jsx`:

**Chevron.jsx**

```
import React from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components'

const StyledChevron = styled.i`
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    padding: 14px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-left: 1px solid #efefef;
    transition: all .1s linear;
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    ${props=>props.closed && ``};
    &:hover {
        background: #f7f4f4;
    }
`

const Chevron = (props) => {

    return (
        <StyledChevron closed={props.item.closed} onClick={()=>{props.openSubMenu(props.item.id)}} className={props.icon}/>
    )

}

export default Chevron
```

**Header.jsx**

```
import React from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components'
import cssvars from '../../js/style/vars'
import Chevron from './Chevron'

const StyledHeader = styled.div`
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 11px;
    justify-content: space-between;
    background: ${cssvars.primaryColor};
    h2 {
        font-size: 19px;
        color: #fff;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
    }
`

const BackChevron = Chevron.extend`
    padding: 0
`

const Header = (props) => {

    return (
        <StyledHeader>
            <h2>{props.item.title}</h2>
            <BackChevron {...props} icon="icon-arrow-left"/>
        </StyledHeader>
    )

}

export default Header
```

With the above code, im getting console error: `Uncaught TypeError: _Chevron2.default.extend is not a function`

Comment: But `Chevron` is not a styled component. It **uses** `StyledChevron ` but the fact of usage doesn't make it magically inherit static `extend` method from `StyleChevron`

Comment: I see, so id need to make Chevron its self a styled component, export that then i'll be able to import in other components and `.extend` ? How can i re-write `Chevron.jsx` to be used in that way?

Comment: Take a look at https://www.styled-components.com/docs/basics#styling-any-components

Comment: Hi thanks for that. Its cleared up a lot. Im still unsure of how i would set up some default styled in the root `Chevron` component that i can import and extend else where though? Is this possible with `styled-components` ?

Comment: I have answered my own question, thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: @Samuel Can you show your answer?

Comment: Still no solution in 2019?

Comment: @MarieBeaufort what solution do you looking for?

Answer (score 3):

`styled-components` has some kind of inheritance

**Chevron.jsx**

```
import React from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components'

const StyledChevron = styled.i`
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    padding: 14px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-left: 1px solid #efefef;
    transition: all .1s linear;
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    ${props => props.closed && ``};

    &:hover {
        background: #f7f4f4;
    }
`

const Chevron = (props) => (
    <StyledChevron
      closed={props.item.closed}
      onClick={() => props.openSubMenu(props.item.id)}
      className={props.icon}
    />
)

export default Chevron
```

**Header.jsx**

```
import React from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components'
import cssvars from '../../js/style/vars'
import Chevron from './Chevron'

const StyledHeader = styled.div`
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 11px;
    justify-content: space-between;
    background: ${cssvars.primaryColor};

    h2 {
        font-size: 19px;
        color: #fff;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
    }
`

const BackChevron = styled(Chevron)`
    padding: 0
`

const Header = (props) => (
    <StyledHeader>
        <h2>{props.item.title}</h2>
        <BackChevron {...props} icon="icon-arrow-left"/>
    </StyledHeader>
)

export default Header
```

as said in @yury-tarabanko comment